# "no matching function to call" error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

It is the first time I am writing classes with Qt. I have stored the declarations in a header file and the source code in in another cpp file but I am getting the error in main of no matching function to call to "Name of class: Name of class ()". I will write down my code and give a print screen of the error below this message. Please I am really struggling with this and the solution would help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Class header file (cylinder.h)

```
#ifndef CYLINDER_H
#define CYLINDER_H


class Cylinder
{
private:
    double height;
    double radius;
public:
    Cylinder(double,double);
    double volume();
    double surfaceArea();
};

#endif // CYLINDER_H
```

Class source code (cylinder.cpp)

```
#include "cylinder.h"
#include<math.h>
#define PI 3.142

Cylinder::Cylinder(double r,double h) {
    radius=r;
    height=h; }

double Cylinder::volume(){
    return PI*radius*radius*height; }

double Cylinder::surfaceArea(){
    return 2.0*PI*radius*height+PI*radius*radius; }
```

main.cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cylinder.h"
#include "cylinder.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cylinder c;
    cout<< c.volume(5,5);

    return 0;
}
```

[Error message from Qt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoV9k.png)

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Hi Toby, thanks for the comment. However, that is what I did for this post. I copied the code from Qt and pasted it straight into the text box, highlighted all as code text afterwards. If there is anything I can do to make the code I post simpler to implement into other compilers, I will be glad to hear suggestions from you or other members.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you all for your replies. Since they were all very similar I accepted the first answer that came as soon as I made this post. If you could all your answers I would honestly do it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *two* errors in your code:

1. First is that you use the non-existent default constructor, instead of the one you have defined taking two arguments.
2. The second is that you pass two arguments to the `volume` function, when it doesn't take any arguments.

It seems you have misunderstood how to use objects and member functions.

You code should look something like

```
Cylinder c(5, 5);     // Pass two arguments here
cout<< c.volume();    // Pass no arguments here
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing default constructor

```
Cylinder() {
...
}
```

Or construct in main with

```
Cylinder c(5.,5.);
```

Also

```
double Cylinder::volume()
```

does not accept 2 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you posted you can see two errors:
[first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhsez.png)

-> "candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided" in line 9.You should correct with:

```
Cylinder c(5.0, 5.0);
```

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuGy0.png)

In line 10 of main.cpp you are calling method volume passing 2 arguments, but function volume does expect 0 argument. You should change that line with:

```
cout<< c.volume();
```

One last thing, why are you including the .cpp file? You don't need it